# Setting a user space windows env var in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I have an environment variable defined in my windows settings as a user variable.

It is called `GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN`.

In my Dockerfile I am trying to assign this variable to an environment variable called `GAT` like so:

`ENV GAT=${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}`

This results in the GAT env var to be blank inside my container.

I have seen that it may be possible via docker-compose but that is not a solution for me, as my RUN command relies on this variable.

Comment: You want this variable to be available during run-time or build-time? Because you mentioned a dockerfile and a container.

Comment: Anything you put in a Dockerfile will be very easy to extract afterwards; if it's an `ENV` variable, it will be there in cleartext in `docker inspect the-image` output.  You probably do not want to put any sort of authentication token in a Dockerfile, even as an `ARG`.

Comment: This is why I want to pass in the info from the user space windows ENV vars. The Dockerfiles purpose is to be used only on local machines (for testing consistency across local dev machines and CI)

I need this variable to be available at build time, as my RUN command inside the Dockerfile relies on it.

This may not be possible and I'd need to rethink, but trying to get confirmation before I pivot towards another solution.

Comment: I am fairly certain that what I'm asking is not possible. 

I have found a workaround, as the package in question is only needed in CI for releaseing and not during testing so I made it an optional dependency (NPM) then ran `npm ci --no-optional` in my image build whereas running `npm ci` in CI will install optionals too.